# Intellisense works only when the module folder is in current workspace

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I made a module recently, for data management. Then I decided to split it into several submodules. However, when I import the module, the auto-complete doesn't work, even though the module itself works perfectly. I found out, that if I keep the module in my workspace, the auto-complete works.

Sample import: `from module.core.client import Client`

The structure of my module directory:

```
module
  module
    core
      __init__.py
      client.py
    extra
      __init__.py
      municipality.py
    modules
      __init__.py
      generic.py
      timetable.py
    __init__.py
    utils.py
  ...
  setup.py
```

If there's any issue with my module set-up, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please provide some more details? What version of VS-Code (I think based on your tags) are you using? Which version of python? What steps have you already taken with regards to checking the 'auto-complete' or IntelliSense settings? That might make it easier to help you, cheers!

Comment: I'm using 1.40.2-1, I tried both python 3.7.5 and 3.8.0. I haven't tinkered with any settings at all. I think there must be a mistake in my package somewhere. Other modules using very similar structure seem to work fine.

Comment: Thanks. And what kind of auto-complete do you mean? All Intellisense features? Or specifically the auto-complete of module names based on your modules?

Comment: Umm no, just the specific module names and parameter suggestions are suddenly gone. I also noticed that when I have two folders in a workspace, when switching between them, python auto-complete stops working. I'm on Manjaro now, but this was an issue even on Windows. Might be related somehow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it was caused by `python setup.py install --user` installing the package as egg. For it to work, I had to do `pip install . --user` from the directory containing `setup.py`